# react-native-twitter-signin does not build on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-twitter-signin

As per the docs https://github.com/react-native-twitter-signin/twitter-signin there is no additional step required but i keep getting error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-twitter-signin_twitter-signin:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-twitter-signin_twitter-signin:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-twitter-signin_twitter-signin

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-twitter-signin_twitter-signin:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-twitter-signin_twitter-signin:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-twitter-signin_twitter-signin
```

Did anyone have this same problem? I did ./gradlew clean but it did not help. On ios, it works ok. Thanks!

Comment: did you find any answer for this error?